# Best way to use Google protocol buffer(protobuf) with Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, protocol-buffers

I am trying to import some protobuf binaries in Matlab. I see 2 ways to do it

1) Use protobuf [Matlab plugin](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-matlab/)

2) Use C++ APIs provided by Google and then import data into matlab using mex files.

Since I am working with large scale data,  Which one would be faster to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster to *run* is likely to be C++, of those two.

I can tell you definitely that coming up to the Matlab-language level for byte, two-byte, four-byte reads or buffer accesses runs a lot slower than you might expect.

And looking in protobuf-matlab/source/browse/protobuflib, I see tons of that type of operation being done in Matlab code.

You didn't list what I would think to be the best of both worlds: the Java API.

If you have any Java code in your project, or a modest level of comfort with Java, I'd strongly consider using the Java API.  Matlab has really good interoperability with Java; it has the big advantage that you can work through examples interactively with methodsview(), etc.  There is some learning curve with javaObject()/javaMethod(), vs. when one can use a more native syntax.